# Missing \endgroup inserted when using \mint in caption?

Tags: captions, minted, code

I'm using [`minted`](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) for code syntax highlighting in my document and it's been working great:

[image]

**In my caption, I want to refer to some variables and format them:**

```
\begin{figure}
    \inputminted{js}{figures/consistency-variables.js}
    \caption{\mint{js}|ConsistencyVariables|}
    \label{fig:consistency-variables}
\end{figure}
```

I tried `\caption{\mint{js}|ConsistencyVariables|}`, but got an error:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

Can I use `\mint` in `\caption` at all? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: `\mint` is like `\verb` and can not be used in the argument to another command.

Comment: Would you get anything different from `\texttt{ConsistencyVariables}`?

Comment: Have you tried `\mintinline`? `\mint` is just a shortcut command for a single-line `minted` environment. `\mintinline` is meant for inline use, and usually works where `\verb` won't as long as you don't need `%`, `#`, or unpaired `{}`.

Comment: @G.Poore thank you `\mintinline` works! yay!

Comment: @G.Poore Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `\mintinline`. `\mint` is just a shortcut command for a single-line `minted` *environment*, which isn't what you usually want in a caption. `\mintinline` is meant for inline use, and usually works where `\verb` won't as long as you don't need `%`, `#`, or unpaired `{}`.